# MySQL replication multi-master with dynamic IPs to single slave

Tags: mysql, linux, networking, openvpn

So I have a collection of data gathering devices that run MySQL and OpenVPN. The OpenVPN runs in either TCP or UDP, but not both and uses different subnets for each and the mode can switch based on availability. In MySQL 5.7, multi-master replication requires a static IP address. This is not a problem if the IP addresses didn't change on the devices, but they do.

How can I make MySQL multi-master replication work with an indeterminate master address?

Comment: If the "devices" are running openvpn, I don't see the problem.  A private address through the tunnel would not need to change; openvpn would worry about the dynamic addresses, not MySQL.  Otherwise, you'll need to clarify how you discover the device's new address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign static IP addresses based on certificate CN's:
http://michlstechblog.info/blog/openvpn-set-a-static-ip-address-for-a-client/

I believe that it also should work on user/password authentication...

Comment: This is, in fact, what we wound up doing. Thanks for the help! :)